# Hibernate/Spring: Session still closed before retrieval of child collection even with @Transactional on Service method

Tags: hibernate, spring, session, spring-mvc, lazy-loading

Hello Spring/Hibernate Gurus!

in a time like this i would like you to be my best friends.I am working on a project using hibernate 3.6.1.Final JPA implementation using session and spring 3.0.5.RELEASE with maven.So with maven project is split in 3 modules model module, service module and webapp module.

where is snippet of the model applicationContext

```
       <!-- Transaction Management    -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- Model -->
<bean id="genericDAO" class="com.blabla.blabla.model.dao.hibernate.HibernateGenericDAOImpl" abstract="true">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>



<bean id="content" class="com.blabla.blabla.model.ContentImpl" scope="prototype" />

<bean id="contentDAO" class="com.blabla.blabla.model.dao.hibernate.ContentDAOImpl" parent="genericDAO">
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>com.blabla.blabla.model.ContentImpl</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

I will also put a snippet of the mapping on the relation giving me nightmares right now so i won't dump everything here:

```
//ContentImpl
@Id
@Column(name = "CONTENT_ID")
private Long ID;
@Version
@Column(name = "OBJ_VERSION")
private int version = 0;
//.... other properties

@OneToMany(targetEntity = ContentImageImpl.class,cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "CONTENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "CONTENT_ID")
private Set<ContentImage> images = new HashSet<ContentImage>();

//ContentImageImpl
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "CONTENT_IMAGE_ID")
private Long ID;

@Column(name = "PATH")
private String path;

@Column(name ="IS_DEFAULT")
private Boolean isDefault;
//no other relations


//ContentServiceImpl
 public class ContentServiceImpl implements ContentService {
//wired from application context
private ContentDAO contentDao;
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ContentServiceImpl.class);

@Transactional
public List<Content> getContentsbyCategoryID(Long categoryId) {
    return getContentDao().getbyCategoryID(categoryId);
}


@Transactional
public List<Content> getContentsWithImagesbyCategoryID(Long categoryId) {
//return getContentDao().getbyCategoryID(categoryId);
    return getContentDao().getWithImagesbyCategoryID(categoryId);



//ContentDAOImpl
 public List<Content> getbyCategoryID(Long category_id) {
    Category cat = modelManager.createCategory();
    cat.setID(category_id);
    logger.info("calling  getbyCategoryID");
    logger.debug(category_id);
    List<Content> session =  this.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(this.getPersistentClass())
            .add(Restrictions.eq("category",(CategoryImpl)cat))
            .setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.id()))
            .list();
    logger.debug(session);
    return session;
}
```

so when assessing `contentService.getContentbyCategoryId(longid)`
it throws

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of  role: com.bla.bla.model.ContentImpl.contentFiles, no session or session was closed
```

really bothers me the only temporal fix i did is to mark this association to eager fetch which am not ok with.I thought puttin @transactional on top of the service method would take care of opening new session when none is opened?

Please advise and thanks for reading this

Answer (score 1):

Does this happen when rendering the view?
If it is the case you might want to consider using Spring's `OpenSessionInViewFilter`. This will bind the Session to the thread for the entire processing of the request. If using JPA you can use `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter`.

In your web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

The scope of the transaction (and hence the session) is only around the `getContentsbyCategoryID()` method. Once you return from it, the transaction is committed and the session is closed. Where, exactly, is it throwing the exception? Is it on the `list()` operation inside `getContentsbyCategoryID()`? Or is it, in fact, after you have returned from `getContentsbyCategoryID()` and trying to access the lazy collection somewhere else in the code? In that case, you either have to

1. increase the scope of the transaction (and, hence, the session)
2. change fetch-type to eager
3. manually load the collection in `getContentsbyCategoryID()` (by calling `size()` on it, for instance)
4. Adopt the open-session-in-view pattern (either through the OpenSessionInViewFilter or the OpenSessionInViewInterceptor)

Comment: Hello , thanks for your explanation it's more clear. i was accessing lazy collection on each object from the list returned by `getContentsbyCategoryID()` . i was trying your openSessioninViewFilter but wasn't working as in am getting the same result