# how to configure DispatcherServlet and ContextLoaderListener in order to give way to OpenViewInSessionFilter

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, servlets, spring-mvc, web.xml

I've been have some issues with my transaction manager using spring 3.0.5 and hibernate 3.6.1.
After finding out that i needed an `OpenViewInSessionFilter` in a post on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274949/hibernate-spring-session-still-closed-before-retrieval-of-child-collection-even) i've tried it and it still wasn't working as i was still having `lazyInitializationException`.

i've also found here (due to your comments and knowledge, thanks guys) that both `DispatcherServlet` and `ContextLoaderListener` have each a `sessionFactory` and that `OpenViewInSessionFilter` actually uses the one from `ContextLoaderListener`.

I've also learnt that `DispatcherServlet` can `borrow sessionFactory` from `ContextLoaderLister` but not the other way round.

that said i found it very confusing in the practice as the kind of project am working on needs both to work properly.

my `web.xml` and `application contexts` are available on [pastie](http://pastie.org/3394124)

Can anyone show me how to get the `OpenViewInSessionFilter` working?
 thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't put the configuration in web.xml, just in applicationContext.xml. Next of the viewResolver (I put next to it), include the code:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="openSessionInViewInterceptor" 
              class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Comment: Hello , i did exactely this but still having the same L.I.E. really driving me nuts :(